# Can't upload file to ftp in c#

Tags: c#, file, ftp

can't upload file to ftp this is my code....

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(source);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + filename);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();
ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ftpstream.Close();
File.Delete(source);
```

always an error is occuring at `GetRequestStream()` the command is not recognized... how can I overcome this error ?
Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Post the full error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get "The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized" when I try to run FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067313/get-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-500-syntax-error-command-unrecogniz)

Comment: @iceDragon this the error ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: 
(500) Syntax error, command unrecognized.

Comment: @PaulF its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these two line

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UsePassive= false;
```

then also if it is not working check whether your antivirus is blocking FTP

Comment: I added it but no change same Error

Comment: wbt antivirus ?

Comment: Thanks @Nithin I exit my antivirus now its working fine :)

Comment: `KeepAlive = false` can hardly help with the OP's problem.